# Uniqueness of Weierstrass division for Tate algebras

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis, rigid-analytic-spaces

This question arises from the proof of theorem 8 (Weierstrass division) in chapter 2 of Siegfried Bosch's Lectures on formal and rigid geometry. Given the Tate algebra $T_n =K \langle \zeta_1, \dots, \zeta_n \rangle $ over a complete (nonarchimedean) valued field $K$, and a $\zeta_n$-distinguished element $g \in T_n$  of order $s$, for any $f \in T_n$ there exists a unique $q \in T_n$ and unique polynomial $r \in T_{n-1}[ \zeta_n ]$ of degree $< s$ in $\zeta_n$ such that $f=gq+r$.

Bosch seems to state that this follows from the fact $\vert f \vert = \max ( \vert g \vert \vert q \vert, \vert r \vert) $ but I can't see how.

In the case where $\vert g \vert = 1$ (this is a valid assumption for proving the theorem), $g$ being distinguished of order $s$ means, upon reduction to the residue field $k$, where $\tilde{g}$ is the reduction of $g$, that $\tilde{g} = a_s \zeta_n ^s + \dots + a_0 \zeta_n ^0$, where $a_s$ is in $k^{\ast}$ and $a_i \in k[\zeta_1, \dots, \zeta_{n-1}]$. That $a_i$ is a polynomial and not a power series follows from the fact the Tate algebra consists of power series whose coefficients go to $0$, so all but finitely many coefficients lie in the maximal ideal of the valuation ring of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "order" is what I think it is and behaves how it should behave (I leave that to OP to check), the following should work:

Let $f=gq_1+r_1 = gq_2+r_2$ i.e. $$g(q_2-q_1)=r_2-r_1.$$

The right hand side has degree and hence order $< s$, but $g$ is of order $s$ by assumption, so the left hand side has order $\ge s$ unless $q_2=q_1$. That of course implies $r_1=r_2$.

Reference for the one-dimensional case: [P. Schneider, *Theorie des Anstiegs*](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/Theorie-des-Anstiegs.pdf), Satz 9.11. (Clash of notation: Schneider's $P$ is Bosch's $g$, Schneider's $G$ is Bosch's $q$, Schneider's $Q$ is Bosch's $r$.)

Comment: This is for the uniqueness, for the existence do you lift a solution in the residue field to $O_K/(\pi^m)$ increasing $m$ one by one ?

Comment: Oh I thought OP only asked about uniqueness. Existence is more intricate I presume. Schneider does it by first doing it for polynomials (by induction on degree), then power series, then Laurent series. There might be other ways. I understood OP as saying Bosch's book contains a proof of existence and just leaves the uniqueness to the reader.